# how to select 1st and last in regex to change values

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I gave a textfile and I need to convert into json format  using NIFI in replace text processor and my text file is as below

```
{
   aba":"frae
    1":",
    21":"faceb
    49":"
    2":"dara#dad

 }
{ 
   1aaf":"daer
   22":"12
   21":",
   142":"
   134":"
}
```

now using regular expression i need to replace values of every starting og line with " and ending with ", if , is there i need to skip and when ever i found { or } i need to skip this and if i found }{ in need to replace it with },{   in nifi replace processor 
sample output:-

```
[{
   "aba":"frae",
    "1":"",
    "21":"faceb",
    "49":"",
    "2":"dara#dad"

 },
{ 
   "1aaf":"daer",
   "22":"12",
   "21":"",
   "142":"",
   "134":""
} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file in vs code then press Ctrl+f for start searching, Enable pattern matching, then search for

```
(.*\"):(\"[^,;]*)
```

and replace with

```
"$1:$2"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use java language. You can use String.replaceAll("\{","\[\{") replaceAll("\}","\}\]") and replaceAll("\n","',").Wish can help u.